# Save empty form field as None in Django

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have a `trip` model, and the form asks for a `outbound flight` and an `inbound flight`, that are both ForeignKeys.

How can I save the `inbound flight` as `None`, if no flight is selected and actually allow this form field to be empty.

This is my form:

```
class NewTrip(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewTrip, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['trip_id'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['destination'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['client'].queryset = Clients.objects.all()

    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ('trip_id', 'destination', 'client', 'out_flight', 'hotel', 'in_flight')
```

And this is my model:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    trip_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Ref. Viagem")
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name='Destino')
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Cliente")
    out_flight = models.ForeignKey(Flight, related_name="outbound_flight" ,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Voo Ida")
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotels, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Hotel")
    in_flight = models.ForeignKey (Flight, related_name="inbound_flight", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Voo Regresso")
```

And this is the view:

```
def newtrip(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewTrip(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('trips')
    else:
        form = NewTrip()
    return render(request, 'backend/new_trip.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `blank=True` to your in_flight and out_flight

```
in_flight = models.ForeignKey(..., blank=True)
out_flight = models.ForeignKey(..., blank=True)
```

Comment: Ok, that was imensly simple! Thanks for the help!